# Como realizar um reload em somente uma parte da pagina, a partir de um ID?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando faze um reload só para o conteudo de dentro de um div.

```
<div class="panel-body">                          
   <pre>
     <p  id="content" th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
  </pre>
 </div>
```

Consegui fazer com que a pagina toda se atualiza-se:

```
$(document).ready(function() { setInterval("location.reload(true)", 10000); });
```

Mas aplicando a mesma logica para um ID não deu muito certo:

```
$(document).ready(function() { setInterval("$('#content').reload(true)", 10000); });
```

**Minha duvida:** Como faço para dar um realod somente no conteúdo desse `<div></div>`, a partir de um ID?

Comment: Cara se não me engano o **reload**  por padrão recarrega a url atual ou seja todo documento.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar Ajax para executar uma determinada função de uma URL e atualizar o conteúdo da sua div com o retorno da função. Dessa forma você não estará recarregando toda a sua página. Um exemplo de ajax seria:

```
var formdata = new FormData($("#myform"));
$.ajax({
    url: "exemplo.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    success:function(data){
        $("#div-id").html(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        $("#div-id").html("Mensagem de Erro");
    }
});
```

Você vai encontrar mais detalhes nesse link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: O "#myform" e "#form-id" se referem a quem?

Comment: Desculpe, ficou com um erro ali. O #myform é o ID do formulário que você enviaria para a função, com os dados necessários. A variável formData é que você enviaria no campo 'data'. Editei agora o código.